# My thread pool triggers race conditions but i can't figure out why

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading

Below is my thread pool code. after 3 hours' debugging, i turn to you guys for help ToT. 
Q1: Is there some wrong with my code? It came up some race conditions while i executed this code 
Q2: The sub-threads did not execute before I add sleep() function in my main function, I want to figure that out too. 
PS: I executed this code under unbuntu system.

```
//this is thread_pool.h
#ifndef _THREAD_POLL_H_
#define _THREAD_POLL_H_

#include <list>
#include <vector>
#include <unistd.h>
// #include "locker.h"
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

class thread_pool {
private:
    struct task {
        void (*fun)(void*);
        void* arg;
    };
private:
    int size;       //the num of working threads
    pthread_mutex_t lock;       //a mutex
    sem_t sem;    //semaphore to indicate the num of jobs
    std::list<task> tasks;
    std::vector<pthread_t> threads; 

    const int default_size = 16;
    int is_shutdown;
public:
    thread_pool();
    thread_pool(int num);
    ~thread_pool();
    void add_job(void (*fun)(void*), void* arg);
private:
    static void* work(void* arg);   //the working threads' call back
    void run();                     //the actual function that work() calls
};

#endif
```

```
//this is thread_pool.cpp
#include "thread_pool.h"


thread_pool::thread_pool(int num) : size(num), is_shutdown(0) {
    if (num <= 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "the num of working threads is incorrect\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    pthread_mutex_init(&lock, NULL);
    sem_init(&sem, 0, 0);
    threads.resize(num);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, work, this);
        // printf("thread %d is created\n", threads[i]);
        pthread_detach(threads[i]);
    }    
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
}

thread_pool::thread_pool() : thread_pool(default_size) {}

thread_pool::~thread_pool() {
    is_shutdown = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        sem_post(&sem);
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&lock);
    sem_destroy(&sem);
}

void* thread_pool::work(void* arg) {
    thread_pool* pool = (thread_pool*)arg;
    pool->run();
    return pool;
}

void thread_pool::run() {
    while (true) {
        sem_wait(&sem);
        if (is_shutdown) {
            break;
        }

        pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
        if (tasks.empty()) {
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
            continue;
        }
        // printf("thread %d run\n", pthread_self());
        task tmp = tasks.front();
        tasks.pop_front();
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
        tmp.fun(tmp.arg);
    }
}

void thread_pool::add_job(void (*fun)(void*), void* arg) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    task tmp;
    tmp.fun = fun;
    tmp.arg = arg;
    tasks.push_back(tmp);
    sem_post(&sem);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
}
```

below is the minimal reproducible example, when executing the `main` function, the output of the `fun` contains the same number.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "thread_pool.h"

int idx = 0; 

void func(void* arg) {
    printf("%d\n", *(int*)arg);
    usleep(100);
}

int main() {
    thread_pool tp(8);
    while (1) {
        tp.add_job(func, (void*)&idx);
        idx++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your race detector probably tells you exactly where the race is.  At first glance though, you've got a race on `is_shutdown`.

Comment: `thread_pool::thread_pool() : thread_pool(default_size)` looks wrong. `default_size` isn't initialized yet. Perhaps you should make `default_size` into a `inline static constexpr int default_size = 16;` instead

Comment: Can you also provide a [mre] so that we can reproduce the race?

Comment: Can you create a [mcve]?  This isn't reproducible (can't compile and test it, no `main` function, etc) and not minimal (make some effort to remove or stub parts of the code that do not affect the bug).

Comment: As it stands your code is just a straight up data race.  All the threads get pointers to the same variable `idx`, so they are all reading it concurrently with the main thread modifying it.  On its face that would explain why several jobs might print the same number (if they both happen to read it between successive increments), but in fact since `idx` isn't atomic, it means your entire program has undefined behavior.  You probably wanted to pass a different pointer to each job, e.g. dynamically allocated, though it makes your design awkward because it isn't clear where it can be deallocated.

Comment: @NateEldredge I almost know where the problem is: when sub-thread executes the jobs, i use variable `void* arg` which point to the idx. While executing, the `idx` is constantly changing, as a result the behavior is awkward. Thanks a lot for your sincerely support, it means a lot to me.

Comment: I suggest you add `-g -fsanitize=thread` when compiling. Then run the program and it'll point out the race(s). The first one is that you write to `idx` and read from it from another thread unsynchronized.

Comment: @TedLyngmo After dubuging for hours, i think i have find out where the problem is. But I can't find a solution to solve it. The bug is: when I add a job to thread pool, I transfer the call back function `void (*cb)` and the argument **(void*) arg**. here is the problem: the memory that **arg** pointing to is changing all the time, and it really confuses me. If you know anything, please inform me.

Comment: @Torch The memory `arg` is pointing to should be the address where `idx` is. It should be the same in all the threads. I can't see how that can be changing at all. How did you determine that it is changing all the time? Sidenote: There's really no need to make `idx` a global variable since you provide the address to it when you start each thread. Put it in `main` instead.

Comment: Another query: Are you using some old C++ standard (pre C++11)? If not, why use the platform specific C API `pthread`? Since C++11 there's a standard C++ class, `std::thread`, included in the standard library - so you could write portable code using that instead.

Comment: @TedLyngmo the `idx` example is a minimal reproducible example, I have fixed the problem, anyway, thanks for your support.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot answer your Q1. As some comments point out, it would help if you could provide a minimal reproducible example and a description of the exact error you get.

However, your Q2 is fairly simple: Your program shuts down when `main` returns. If you have started a bunch of threads, then too bad - they will also get torn down by the OS, and most likely in a brutal and exception-inducing fashion.

The normal way around this is to `join` the threads you have created at the end of `main` (or wherever it makes sense). This causes the main thread to wait for the spawned threads to finish.

You instead `detach` your threads, which means that they clean up after themselves when they finish, but it does nothing for extending the life of your `main` thread. So they still get brutally stopped when that one returns.

The `sleep` you mention adding to `main` simply pushes `main` to survive longer, and thus lets the spawned threads run a bit. At the end of the `sleep` `main` still stops and your threads get forcefully torn down (if they are still running).

Comment: i have added the minimal reproducible example, if you know anything, please point it out. PS: English is not my native language, please tolerant my misusing.

Comment: After dubuging for hours, i think i have find out where the problem is. But I can't find a solution to solve it. The bug is: when I add a job to thread pool, I transfer the call back function `void (*cb)` and the argument `(void*) arg`. here is the problem: the memory that `arg` pointing to is changing all the time, and it really confuses me. If you know anything, please inform me.

Comment: @Torch Do you mean that the pointer is changing, or the integer the pointer is pointing to is changing?

Comment: The latter one. I have fixed the bug, anyway, thanks four your generous support.

Answer (score 0):

After 2 days' debugging, I find out the bug and fix it.

Q1: The reason why my code triggers race conditions, like the minimal reprodicible example `main`, is because when passing a job to the thread pool, the argument `arg` points to the memory which changes all the time. So, these race conditions can be easily fixed using deep copy.

Q2: The cause of this bug may be time slices are not allocated for sub-threads. I am not famaliar with Linux scheduling algorithm, so I added `sleep` function in the main thread to force the main thread to sleep so that sub-threads can have the chance to execute.

Comment: _"I added `sleep` function in the main thread to force the main thread to sleep so that sub-threads can have the chance to execute"_ - That's almost always the wrong solution. Use synchronizing mechanisms like mutexes, condition variables and atomics.

Comment: @TedLyngmo My main thread add jobs to the `thread_pool` class in which i use `detach` to enable sub-threads to deal with themselves later. The main question that bothered me is that my sub-threads did not have the time slices to execute while main-thread was executing all the time, and I don't know why. So if you know something about this, please inform me.

Comment: The anticipated situation is that after jobs being added to the thread pool, the main thread and the sub-thread can execute concurrently, while my code did not ever execute the sub-thread once until main-thread exits